# Subclassing UIView containing multiple UIViews

Tags: ios, uiview, subclassing, addsubview

I want to create a UIView subclass which will in its initializer add a UIView to its own view, like:

```
    [self addSubview: someKindOfUIView];
```

This is how I've implemented it in the implementation file:

```
- (id)init
{
     self = [super initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 110, 110)];
     if (self) {

        self.grayView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 20, 20)]; 
        self.grayView.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];

        [self addSubview:self.grayView];
        [self setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor]];

    }

   return self;
}
```

But when I try to use instances of this class, the instances only show a bluebox, not a blue box containing a gray box. How can i fix that, is it possible? :)

Comment: are you by chance creating it using the initializer `-initWithFrame:` and not the one you have implemented (`-init`)?

Comment: Sadly I use the right one, the (-init).

Comment: alright -- just thought i'd quick check because it deviated from the norm. are you using the class in resources the framework loads (e.g. NIBs)?

Comment: or you can just sanity check by implementing `-initWithFrame:` and `-initWithCoder:` and putting asserts in there, to see if your class is loaded by the frameworks (they will not call your initializer).

Comment: Can you clarify if you're using IB/Storyboarding to add this view or are you doing it programmatically?

Comment: How are you adding this custom view to your window? Do you make it a subview of a controller's view, for instance?

Comment: @k-bear, Please share some more code showing how you are creating objects for this view.

Comment: @Ninja im creating it programmatically

Comment: @rdelmar im adding this view to a tableviewcontroller by sending it: [self.tableView addSubview: someInstanceOfTheCustomUIView], this works but it only shows a blue box, instead of a blue box containing a gray box

Comment: @ACB I will upload more asap ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, after some testing and research I found the answer!

In my .h file I had a weak pointer to the grayView property:

@property (nonatomic,**weak**) UIView *grayView;

Instead, it should be:

@property (nonatomic,**strong**) UIView *grayView;

I sorta understand why, but i can't explain it in a good way, so if anyone can explain why (in an easy way) grayView has to have a strong pointer instead of a weak one, please comment under this answer ;)

Comment: I would guess that the view assign to `grayView` will be released immediately and also the `grayView` property will be set to `nil` so you end up adding a `nil` subview.

Comment: This doesn't seem right. It shouldn't be released immediately since weak objects won't be set to `nil` when there's a strong reference. By adding it to `subview`, you've created a strong reference. Very odd...